# What can be said about type of lambda closure defined in function template?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

I know that lambda's type is "hidden" and unique. But what is precisely the meaning of "unique", in peculiar do identical lambda codes give the same type?

(If possible) I would like to use this "invariant" for type checking, as illustrated here:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto foo(const T y)
{
  return [=](T x) { return x * y; }; 
}

int main()
{
  auto f1 = foo<int>(4.);
  auto f2 = foo<int>(6.); // fails with auto f2 = foo<double>(6.);

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f1), 
                               decltype(f2)>); // is this ok or undefined behavior?
}
```

Before that I want to be sure of what the c++ standard says: is it ok or undefined behavior?

(this code is successfully compiled by g++ and clang++, but only the standard truth matter)

---

As a complement more conforms to the initial title (sorry this comes a little bit late because I had to leave my office), here is a stronger version that does **not** compile:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto foo_1(const T y)
{
  return [=](T x) { return x * y; };
}

template <typename T>
auto foo_2(const T y)
{
  return [=](T x) { return x * y; };
}

int main()
{
  auto f1 = foo_1<int>(4.);
  auto f2 = foo_2<int>(6.);

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f1), decltype(f2)>); // fails!
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems like `foo<int>` is a function and a function has a specific return type. So every objects it returns would need to have the same type. I suspect that due to this `f1` and `f2` necessarily have the same types.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's an interesting remark, thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure) is what the standard has to say about closure types.

Comment: Imho, the title doesn't match the question body. You don't have identical lambda expressions, you have *one* lambda (expression `[...](...){...}` appears once) (more precisely, you have one per template instantination, but there is only one instantination here).

Comment: Based solely on the question title, [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/QUIzZX) might answer that question. The compilers I tried did not consider identical lambdas to have identical types.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat absolutely agree. That what got me into giving completely wrong answer on the first attempt.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title, as it is confusing and misguiding. At least two people (myself included) answered question incorrectly because of that.

Comment: If you change the template to `template <typename T, int DUMMY>`, and use `auto f1 = foo<int, 1>(4.);` and `auto f2 = foo<int, 2>(6.);` ... does that shed any light?  Or irrelevant to the question?

Comment: @sergeyA I have updated my post, a little bit late (sorry I had to leave the office and drive back home)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, got it and you are right, I also updated the post: "complement" update.

Comment: `template <typename T>
auto foo_1(const T y)`  ... `const` is redundant in both `foo_1` and `foo_2`, signatures. As for the answer simply replace lambdas with what compiler does when transforming them into uniquely named functors. HTH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that the standard doesn't say exactly what "unique" means, but I think we can figure it out.

First, notice that the standard says "unique, unnamed non-union class type". The adjective "unnamed" is strong enough to imply that a lambda closure type is never the same as some named class defined using the `struct` or `class` keyword or by the standard library (for example, a lambda closure type cannot be `std::function<...>`).

So why does the standard say "unique, unnamed"? It must be telling us something about comparison between two different lambda closure types. Still, that would be redundant in many cases. If we had two lambda expressions like:

```
auto f1 = [](int x) { return x; };
auto f2 = [](int x) { return 2*x; };
```

it is clear that the two lambda expressions cannot have the same type, because their function call operators have different behaviours. Therefore, the statement that the closure type of each is "unique" would not tell us anything we don't already know about `f1` and `f2`.

However, if we now look at:

```
auto f3 = [](int x) { return x; };
auto f4 = [](int x) { return x; };
```

Here, "unique" can be interpreted as saying that `f3` and `f4` definitely have different types, even though the lambda expressions have the same spelling and the same behaviour.

This is generally accepted as the meaning of "unique" in this context. If the standard didn't mean to say that `f3` and `f4` have different types, there would be no reason to use the word "unique" at all. Instead, it would just say "unnamed", not "unique, unnamed".

The question then arises as to how far uniqueness extends. Can it possibly mean that each evaluation of the lambda expression yields a different type? No, it can't possibly mean that. That would make the static type of an expression depend on how many times it has been executed (a runtime property), which is absurd. Consider what would happen if your `foo<int>`'s lambda had a different type every time `foo<int>` was executed. It would mean `foo<int>`'s signature would change every time it's called. This cannot be. The lambda in `foo<int>` must always have the same type.

As for your `foo_1` and `foo_2` situation, the two lambda types there must be different. Again, if this were not so, the word "unique" would be redundant.

Comment: Excellent deduction my dear Sherlock, although, I might allow my self for this complete program to give me all the answers, I need on the same subject. -- https://wandbox.org/permlink/V3TJb20cKjgY2Bi2

Comment: "No, it can't possibly mean that." -- I think we can also build an argument around ODR?  But I guess the conclusion would only be "if this was true, you could never use lambdas", which isn't ruled out in theory.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

The assert you're doing is not undefined behavior. The closure type is impl-defined. Once you're comparing the lambda-expression types in the same compiler, there's no problem.

Comment: Is it though? I thought that only things the standard mandated to be implementation defined could be considered implementation define. I don't see that in the Closure Type section [(7.5.5.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure) so I'm not sure the term applies. Unless I missed it or misunderstood the nature of implementation defined behavior. Edit : In addition, implementation defined behavior is required to be documented by the implementation. I don't know if I know of any implementation that documents the types of closures they use.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it is called 'unnamed' type with defined properties. It is not implementation defined as per Standard.

Comment: I agree it isn't UB; but you haven't demonstrated it is impl-defined.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I might be so bold to assume if one repeats this in each compiler the output will be sufficiently different to allow one to claim "impl-definedness" -- https://wandbox.org/permlink/V3TJb20cKjgY2Bi2

Comment: of course one has to add this will allow for meeting head-on, weird and wonder full and ridiculous, differences among C++ compilers of today ...

Comment: @ChefGladiator Implementation defined is a term in the standard; in a sense, everything is defined by the implementation when you run the implementation.  Acting different is *evidence*, but could just be a bug in one or more compilers.

Comment: What is in doubt here, if anything?